# Class attribute not working on EditorFor/TextBoxFor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to apply a js plugin on a table where the rows are populated by a `List` property on my model object. However, neither `@class` attribute is taking.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    //These all work
    $('#HomePhone').mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
    $('#BusinessPhone').mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
    $('#MobilePhone').mask("(999) 999-9999");
    $('#FaxNumber').mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
    $('#Birthdate').mask("99/99/9999");
    $('#HomeZip').mask("99999?-9999");
    $('#MailingZip').mask("99999?-9999");
    $('#LocationZip').mask("99999?-9999");
    $('#LifeEAPercent').mask("9.99");
    $('#VARPercent').mask("9.99");

    //These don't
    $("#relCodeEffDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    });
    $("#relDistCode").numeric();
});
```

**Razor**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AgentRelationshipCodes.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AgentRelationshipCodes[i].RelationshipId, new {@class="relDistCode", maxlength = 3})
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AgentRelationshipCodes[i].EffectiveDate, "NullableDate", new {@class = "relCodeEffDate"})
        </td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AgentRelationshipCodes[i].ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AgentRelationshipCodes[i].ID)
    </tr>
}
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="relDistCode" id="AgentRelationshipCodes_0__RelationshipId" maxlength="3" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[0].RelationshipId" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>                                                       
        <input class="form-control" id="AgentRelationshipCodes_0__EffectiveDate" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[0].EffectiveDate" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="AgentRelationshipCodes_0__ID" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[0].ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <input id="AgentRelationshipCodes_0__ID" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[0].ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="relDistCode" id="AgentRelationshipCodes_1__RelationshipId" maxlength="3" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[1].RelationshipId" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>                                                       
        <input class="form-control" id="AgentRelationshipCodes_1__EffectiveDate" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[1].EffectiveDate" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="AgentRelationshipCodes_1__ID" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[1].ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <input id="AgentRelationshipCodes_1__ID" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[1].ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="relDistCode" id="AgentRelationshipCodes_2__RelationshipId" maxlength="3" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[2].RelationshipId" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>                                                       
        <input class="form-control" id="AgentRelationshipCodes_2__EffectiveDate" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[2].EffectiveDate" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="AgentRelationshipCodes_2__ID" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[2].ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <input id="AgentRelationshipCodes_2__ID" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[2].ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="relDistCode" id="AgentRelationshipCodes_3__RelationshipId" maxlength="3" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[3].RelationshipId" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>                                                       
        <input class="form-control" id="AgentRelationshipCodes_3__EffectiveDate" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[3].EffectiveDate" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="AgentRelationshipCodes_3__ID" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[3].ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <input id="AgentRelationshipCodes_3__ID" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[3].ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="relDistCode" id="AgentRelationshipCodes_4__RelationshipId" maxlength="3" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[4].RelationshipId" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>                                                       
        <input class="form-control" id="AgentRelationshipCodes_4__EffectiveDate" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[4].EffectiveDate" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="AgentRelationshipCodes_4__ID" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[4].ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <input id="AgentRelationshipCodes_4__ID" name="AgentRelationshipCodes[4].ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are Class, and not id. use period and not hash:

```
    $(".relCodeEffDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    });
    $(".relDistCode").numeric();
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure about downvoting your own question but you can definitely accept my answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I completely missed the class/id hash/period in the answer below, but a second layer to this problem was the `NullableDate` helper I'm using. This was set to give the helper a class of `form-control`. I needed to change the class inside the partial view like so for the `datepicker` to work.

```
@model DateTime?

@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty), new { @class = "relCodeEffDate" })
```